# Alternative to Random.Next method

Tags: vb.net

In visual basic, is there a method that will allow me to select a random number from a list of numbers, rather than selecting a random number between two numbers?

In other words, I want something like `Random().Next(1, 3, 4, 6, 7)` where it will select a random number from those numbers (so selecting 2 is not an option)

I've looked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/), but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Put those numbers in a List/Array and pick a random index from the List/Array indexes: `Dim i as Integer = MyList([Random].Next(0, MyList.Count))` / `MyArray([Random].Next(0, MyArray.Length))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1
Private Function NextRandom(ParamArray numbers() As Integer) As Integer
    Dim Result As Integer = Integer.MinValue

    If numbers.Length > 0 Then
        Dim rnd As New Random
        Dim i As Integer = rnd.Next(0, numbers.Length)
        Result = numbers(i)
    End If

    Return Result
End Function

Public Sub Main()
    Console.writeline("Your next number is: {0}", NextRandom(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
End Sub
End Module
```

More info and examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Working example of the code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M8z4uM)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Define your list as an array:

```
Dim List = New Integer() {Your numbers here}
```

Then use the standard random.next to generate an index for the array:

```
Dim generator As New Random
Dim index As Integer
index = generator.Next(0, List.length)
```

Then define your random number as the number that corresponds to the index in the array:

```
Dim randNumber as Integer
randNumber = List(index)
```

Comment: Read the documentation of next [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_) the maxValue is exclusive, that means that it is excluded from the resulting number so the line of your code "index = generator.Next(0, List.length - 1)" is wrong because it will never return the last number in the array...

Answer (score 0):

If you want each value in your list only once then just shuffle your list.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lst As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 3, 4, 6, 7}
    Dim shuffledList As List(Of Integer) = lst.OrderBy(Function(i) Rnd.Next()).ToList()
    For Each i In shuffledList
        Debug.Print(i.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

You get a different order each time you click the button.